# Export Multple Rows from Access to Word Document

Tags: ms-access

Ok, my VBA skills are beginner at best…  Here is what I am attempting to accomplish….  I am trying to take multiple rows of data from a table, and export it as a table to a Word document.  So, multiple rows associated with a client would populate the table to be exported.

The Access table is Schedule and the fields are Message and Rate.

The to the Word Document would be (with gridlines included):

---

| Your Percentage for X will be |  5.00% |
| Your Percentage for Y will be |  4.00% |
| Your Percentage for Z will be |  3.75% |

---

To add a wrinkle to it, when  I run this routine, a new document will need to be created for each entity created in the table.

So, an instance of word would be opened and saved as Business A with its corresponding table, then Business B, and so on…

Business A.doc
Business B.doc

and so on

HELP!

Comment: To add...  I cannot use a report and export to Word or PDF because the ither formatting will not work (ie: justified verbiage and gridlines)

Comment: There is no simple solution for this. Function like Excel's CopyFromRecordset doesn't exist in Word. But you can use tables in Word - add new rows and fill cells in cycle. Search for inserting data in Word tables, it's not complicated.